# Phonegap slide transition effect on pages without any UI framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Currently i am working in phonegap responsive mobile application.I am not using jquery mobile or any other UI framework.I want to slide left/right transition effect on pages.I am not getting proper solution for page slide transition. Someone help me with this as i don't know how to implement such effect?